# Eclipse & EMF - children of element also visible as attributes

Tags: eclipse, xsd, schema, emf, ecore

I've got a bit of the problem with EMF

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeElement">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="SomeContents" type="cfg:SomeContents" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="SomeContents" abstract="true">
</xs:complexType>
```

Basically in example given above SomeElement is supposed to have only children but no properties at all. Unfortunately this does not work and all possible children are also shown as attributes (with no ability to edit them). Code is pretty much generated by Eclipse so I believe that there may be something wrong with schema or ecore file.

```
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="SomeElement">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="name" value="SomeElement"/>
      <details key="kind" value="elementOnly"/>
    </eAnnotations>
    <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EReference" name="SomeContents" lowerBound="1"
        eType="#//SomeContents" containment="true" resolveProxies="false">
      <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
        <details key="kind" value="element"/>
        <details key="name" value="SomeContents"/>
        <details key="namespace" value="##targetNamespace"/>
      </eAnnotations>
    </eStructuralFeatures>
</eClassifiers>
<eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="SomeContents" abstract="true">
    <eAnnotations source="http:///org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/ExtendedMetaData">
      <details key="name" value="SomeContents"/>
      <details key="kind" value="empty"/>
    </eAnnotations>
</eClassifiers>
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you have to change something in your generator model instead of changing your source schema.

Open your genmodel, and look for the property that is presented incorrectly as a child element. Then, in the Properties view, look for the Edit category, and check the following settings:

- Children
- Create Child
- Property Type

I believe, these settings were generated in a wrong way when you initialized the generator model, and they are controlling the tree editors children behaviour.

Comment: Ok, that did not solve my problem in this case as children are dynamic (nothing predefined - set of possible children can be changed in runtime) but then it gave me an idea where to look for it and confirmed my initial thoughts that model itself is ok. Thanks for help:)